# Passing string value after apply split function in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have fail to pass the string value to label or text box after split function. So my question is how to store the string value in label after applying the split function.

```
string strData2 = "samsung,apple,htc";       
char[] separator2 = new char[] { ',' };
string[] strSplitArr = strData2.Split(separator2);
foreach (string arrStr in strSplitArr)
{
       Response.Write(arrStr + "<br/>");

}
```

(e.g. label.text = ""+ *the split string value* )
Thanks

Comment: `text = String.Join(",",strSplitArr)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
label.Text = String.Join("," , strSplitArr);
```

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
label.text = label.text + arrStr;
```

to list one after other with break, do

```
label.text = label.text + arrStr + "</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to join these in one string again? Use String.Join:

```
label.Text += String.Join(' ',strSplitArr);
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/57a79xd0.aspx